# How to use git pull with Jenkins sh steps?

Tags: git, jenkins, sh

`git pull` doesn't work with Jenkins for some reason.
I've updated some files on my local PC and pushed it to my Github. I can see the changes there. Then I run Jenkins build that has sh commands to pull from this repo and it says "Already up to date". Which is false as I clearly pushed new version to Github and if I go there and open up the file in my browser I can see the changes.
This only happens with Jenkins running git pull because if I connect to my VM and run `git pull` myself it works fine and updates my files. Why does this happen?

My Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages{
    stage("build"){
      steps{
        echo 'build'
        sh 'cd /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/scripts'
        sh 'eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"'
        sh 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519'
        sh 'git pull git@github.com:mightyajax/scripts.git'
      }
    }
    stage("test"){
      steps{
        echo 'test'
      }
    }
    stage("deploy"){
      steps{
        echo 'deploy'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, each `sh '...'` command in Jenkins is run through a **separate /bin/sh process**, so any changes to process-level environment only remain while that specific command is running.

For example, the `cd` in 'sh' line #1 only affects the first /bin/sh instance – as soon as that line is processed, the shell exits and all changes are lost. Line #2 is then processed in a brand new /bin/sh which inherits the *original* working directory from Jenkins. (So you're getting wrong results from "git pull" because you are *in* the wrong repository at that time.)

Similarly, when 'sh' line #2 sets some environment variables (namely SSH_AUTH_SOCK) through the eval, they are also immediately lost when the shell exits, so the subsequent 'ssh-add' doesn't know where the agent is.

```
Jenkins                                Interactive

jenkins                                sshd
├─ shell                               └─ shell
│  └─ cd /var/atlassian/etc               ├─ cd /var/atlassian/etc
├─ shell                                  ├─ eval $(ssh-agent)
│  └─ eval $(ssh-agent)                   ├─ ssh-add
├─ shell                                  └─ git pull
│  └─ ssh-add
└─ shell
   └─ git pull
```

To avoid this, run everything as a *single* script:

```
sh: 'cd /var/foo && eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add && git pull <url>'
```

You could also avoid the need for a manual `cd` by using the `-C` option telling Git to do it on its own: `git -C /var/foo pull <url>`.

Comment: worked for me thanks